# How to fix Expected value: "1" Received array: [{"COUNT (*)": "1"}] error in TypeORM with jest framework

Tags: typescript, jestjs, typeorm

I am new to Jest framework and TypeORM, and i am facing an issue in running manager.query statement

I am connecting to the database and instead using a query builder i want to use entity manager to inject a raw query. Below is code -

```
import {createDBConnection} from "../utils/createDBConnection";

test(" Count", async () =>{
  jest.setTimeout(100000);
  const connection = await createDBConnection();
  const usercount= await connection.manager.query("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM User");
  expect(usercount).toContain('32');
});
```

Below is the expected and actual output.

```
expect(received).toContain(expected) // indexOf

    Expected value: "32"
    Received array: [{"COUNT (*)": "32"}]
```

Comment: Is that not the expected output of a raw query?

Comment: The result should be - 
Expected Value: "32"
Received Value : "32"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running a raw query through TypeORMs API. When you run a raw query, TypeORM will return raw results which in this case is an array of rows from your SQL server. You need will need to parse result to get the count e.g:

```js
const key = "user_count";
const usercount= await connection.manager.query(`SELECT COUNT (*) as ${key} FROM User`);
expect(usercount.length).toEqual(1);
expect(usercount[0][key]).toEqual("32");
```

Alternatively you can use the repository API to get the count:

```js
const usercount = await getRepository(User).count();
expect(usercount).toEqual(32);
```